# Why OpenZeppelin's ERC1155 contract is mintable from only owner?

Tags: solidity, nft, openzeppelin

I'm trying to build an NFT marketplace. So I wanted to create an ERC1155 smart contract to allow content creators to put their art into the smart contract. I'm using OpenZeppelins [wizard](https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/#erc1155) as a base but I found some weirdness on the mint function. It's allowing only the owner of the contract to mint:

[image: mint function is marked as only owner]

It's made me suspicious about my actions. Should I disallow users to mint to create items on my contract?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the wizard authors why they decided on some specific approach.

However it's an established practice that when an artist or any other authorized person publishes an NFT collection, they don't want other people to contribute to this specific collection and change the overall meaning of it. For example, if you have a collection of NFTs representing pictures of dogs, you might not want other people to create NFTs representing pictures of cats in the same collection. Or any other unrelated pictures for that matter.

If you want to allow minting tokens in the collection by anyone, you can remove the `onlyOwner` modifier from the mint functions As well as the `Ownable` extension of `MyTokens` contract and its import, assuming you don't use the `Ownable` features elsewhere in your contract.